# How to collapse an xmlToDataframe into a single row

Tags: r, xml

How can I convert an xml to a single row dataframe without losing the child nodes.

This is my code minus the query, I've tried different combinations of foo but they don't do what I want.

```
xmltmp=xmlParse(xml)
xmlr=xmlRoot(xmltmp)
foo=xmlr[[1]]
xmldf=xmlToDataFrame(foo, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

```
> xmlr
<submission xmlns="http://opendatakit.org/submissions" xmlns:orx="http://openrosa.org/xforms">
  <data>
    <odk_chmin2 id="odk_chmin2" instanceID="uuid:748ffcc4-c4a2-4341-b613-fd3d0b7e83bd" version="20180531" submissionDate="2018-11-14T09:05:15.228-06:00" isComplete="true" markedAsCompleteDate="2018-11-14T09:05:15.228-06:00">
      <colecta>
        <cve_orig>IOR2015LI000559</cve_orig>
        <fecha>2015-04-18</fecha>
        <sitio>NTP2</sitio>
      </colecta>
      <geo_temp>
        <temp>14.2700000000</temp>
        <precip>9.5000000000</precip>
        <veg>pino_encinoNTP</veg>
       </geo_temp>
       ...
     </odk_chmin2>
  </data>
  <mediaFile>
  ...
  </mediaFile>
  ...
</submission>
```

```
 cve_orig      fecha sitio          temp       precip            veg
1 IOR2015LI000559 2015-04-18  NTP2 14.2700000000 9.5000000000 pino_encinoNTP
```

I'd like my results in a single row but from my previous results:
foo=xmlr[[1]] does a single row but concatenates the child nodes

```
 colecta                        geo_temp
1 IOR2015LI0005592015-04-18NTP2 14.27000000009.5000000000pino_encinoNTP
```

On the other hand foo=xmlr[[1]][[1]] labels the columns correctly but adds a row for each node, how can I can collapse it into a single row?

```
 cve_orig      fecha sitio          temp       precip            veg
1            <NA>       <NA>  <NA>          <NA>         <NA>           <NA>
2 IOR2015LI000559 2015-04-18  NTP2          <NA>         <NA>           <NA>
...
9            <NA>       <NA>  <NA> 14.2700000000 9.5000000000 pino_encinoNTP
```

Answer (score 0):

I am starting from xmlr. Should work even if you start from your xml. The idea is to use xmlToList to flatten the fields.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(XML)

my_tree = xmlTreeParse(xmlr)
my_root = xmlRoot(my_tree) 
my_children = xmlChildren(my_root)

df = xmlToList(my_children$data) %>% 
  unlist %>% 
  data.frame(X1=.) %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  spread(rowname, X1)
```